# Is $SU(2)$ a retract of $U(2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

*Is $SU(2)$ a retract of $U(2)$?*

Notice that $U(2) \to SU(2), A\mapsto (\det A)^{-1/2} A$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in $S^1\stackrel \gamma\longrightarrow U(n)\stackrel \det\longrightarrow S^1$, where $\gamma(z)$ is the identity matrix with first diagonal element replaced by $z$, the composition is the identity. A rectration of $U(n)$ to $SU(n)$ would therefore result in a retract $S^1$ to $\{1\}$.